# SatelliteMenuItem Text with image inandroid

Tags: android, android-layout, satellite-image

Hi friend i am adding  SatelliteMenu in program Like this

```
 SatelliteMenuItem a1=new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_4);

    List<SatelliteMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<SatelliteMenuItem>();
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_1));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(4, R.drawable.ic_3));
    items.add(a1);
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(3, R.drawable.ic_5));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(2, R.drawable.ic_6));
   items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(1, R.drawable.ic_2));
    menu.addItems(items);
```

But problem is i am not able to set Text with  SatelliteMenuItem image.
 Please suggest me how i can add text with Image in  SatelliteMenuItem

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: need to change in `SatelliteMenuItem` class in library project...

Comment: How can i change this class or there is any other Library ?

Comment: Not exactly known but you need to add String parameter to `SatelliteMenuItem's Constructor` then add this string as menu item text .... but i think in this menu icon with text no look better ...so no need to add text if not extremely needed ...

Comment: no i am adding text like this    "Facebook" facebook image  & "Twitter" Twitter image

Comment: i think hard to change in lib project for you so better way to do this with creating image with text and icon as you want .....

Answer (score 0):

You have to change SatelliteMenuItem's Constructor like as it is...

```
public SatelliteMenuItem(int id, int imgResourceId,String string) {
    this.imgResourceId = imgResourceId;
   this.string=string;
    this.id = id;
}    

public SatelliteMenuItem(int id, Drawable imgDrawable,String string) {
    this.imgDrawable = imgDrawable;
    this.string=string;
    this.id = id;
}
```

Its the libs SatelliteMenuItem. add one parameter more as String or Textview, 
try some methods given below in this class.
May be This give you some idea.